# Why is the map in this proof for manifolds a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The theorem that we proved in class is:

> Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m} $ be a submanifold of dimension $n$.
> Then, for every point $a \in M$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ for
> $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and diffeomorphism $\Phi: U \to V \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, such that $ \Phi(U \cap M) = V \cap (\mathbb{R}^n
>  \times \{ 0 \}^m) $.

In the proof we used the graph characterization of manifold;

> A nonempty subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is a submanifold of
> dimension $n$ iff for every point $a \in M$ there exists an open
> neighbourhood $U \ni a$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and a permutation of
> coordinates $\sigma: (x_1, \ldots, x_{n+m}) \mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},
>  \ldots, x_{\sigma{(n+m)}})$, such that $M \cap U = \{ (x_{\sigma(1)},
>  \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}, \varphi(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)})
>  \; | \; (x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)} ) \in D \}$.

Now, the proof is as follows;

> Locally, $M$ is a graph over one of its $n$-dimensional coordinate
> subspaces; $M \cap U = \{ ( x, \varphi(x) \; | \; x \in D \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^n, \varphi: D \to \mathbb{R}^m )   \}  $ (coordinates in
> $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} = \mathbb{R}_x^n \times \mathbb{R}_y^m$). We can
> define $\Phi(x,y) := (x, y - \varphi(x) )$ with inverse
> $\Phi^{-1}(x,z) = (x, z + \varphi(x ))$, both defined on $D \times
> \mathbb{R}^m$. The derivative is $$ \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -D
>  \varphi(x) & I  \end{bmatrix} $$ This map $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism
> of $D \times \mathbb{R}^m$ onto itself and in addition, $\Phi(M \cap
>  U) = D \times \{ 0 \}^m$.

I can't see why $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism. I think what we could do is to invoke the inverse function theorem, but to do so, we might need to make $U$ a little bit smaller. However, I don't think this is what we have done here, since for that, we wouldn't need to write the inverse explicitly. However, if we wanted to show that it's a diffeomorphism from definition ($C^1$ bijection with $C^1$ inverse), we would have to show that it is also a bijection. We only showed that $\det (D \Phi) \neq 0$, but isn't that insufficient globally, for example, $(x,y) \mapsto (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$ is not injective.

Comment: First, your definition in the beginning has a typo, it should say *"there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$"*. Also, your map $\Phi$ is clearly a diffeomorphism because $\Phi:D\times\Bbb{R}^m\to D\times\Bbb{R}^m$, $\Phi(x,y)=(x,y-\varphi(x))$ has an explicitly defined smooth inverse function: just replace $-$ with $+$. You have a smooth map with a smooth inverse, which is literally the definition of a diffeomorphism. This is one of those fortunate situations where you don't need the inverse function theorem. In light of this, the computation of $D\Phi$ is a red-herring.

Comment: thank you @peek-a-boo !